# Argo Workflow always using default serviceaccount

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argo-workflows, argoproj

I installed the default helm chart of Argo Workflow with only configuring init.serviceAccount as argo-sa, which I have created. (ServiceAccount with enough authorization)
However, running every Workflow runs as serviceaccount Default, which I can’t figure out where the setting is configured.
According to the README provided by Argo Helm Chart, specifying `init.serviceAccount` as the serviceaccount which I have created should solved the problem.
The workaround is to modify the Default serviceaccount, but it seems that it's not a great solution.
Is there anything that I understood incorrectly ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Argo installation does not control which ServiceAccount Workflows use. According to the [Argo docs](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/3507c3e6e8e9c420a6028a43b930a3ef6b221705/docs/service-accounts.md),

> When no ServiceAccount is provided [when the Workflow is submitted], Argo will use the default
> ServiceAccount from the namespace from which it is run, which will
> almost always have insufficient privileges by default.

If you are using the [Argo CLI to submit Workflows](https://argoproj.github.io/argo/cli/argo_submit/), you can specify the ServiceAccount with `--serviceaccount`.

If you are using `kubectl apply` or some other tool to install Workflows, you can [set the ServiceAccount name in the yaml definition](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/7abead2a564876a695201cf7539bd20d1fc67888/docs/workflow-rbac.md). See an [example from the documentation](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/da43086a19f88c0b7ac71fdb888f913fd619962b/examples/cron-backfill.yaml#L52), or this abbreviated example:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
spec:
  serviceAccountName: some-serviceaccount
```

As a convenience, the Argo Helm chart [provides a way to create a ServiceAccount](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-helm/blob/master/charts/argo/values.yaml#L28-L33) with which to run your Workflows. But it does not actually *cause* your Workflows to use that ServiceAccount. You have to specify it when you submit the Workflow.

```yaml
  serviceAccount:
    create: false  # Specifies whether a service account should be created
    annotations: {}
    name: "argo-workflow"  # Service account which is used to run workflows
  rbac:
    create: false  # adds Role and RoleBinding for the above specified service account to be able to run workflows
```

Comment: This was super helpful. Thanks Michael!

Comment: @IHateMint you bet!

Comment: I am using a script template in my workflow. When I specify the `serviceAccountName` in the workflow spec and execute the workflow I get, "error looking up service account default/argo: serviceaccount". I know that argo service account exists in argo namespace. Why can't the workflow find it?

Comment: @SSF I wonder if default/argo means it’s looking for the argo sa in the default namespace. Maybe try running the workflow in the argo namespace?

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake. Thanks @MichaelCrenshaw

Comment: One solution is to create a RoleBinding between the default service account in the namespace, and the corresponding argo workflow Role.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the service account in the `workflowDefaults` to run the workflows inside the `helm-values.yaml`:

```
workflowDefaults:
  spec:
    serviceAccountName: argo-workflow-controller
```